# "Type Error: class or module required" for two-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my rails app, I have essentially an "account" and a "transaction" model.  The "transaction" model `belongs_to` the "account" model twice, once as a `credited_account` and once as a `debited_account`.  It looks something like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :credits, :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => 'credited_account_id'
  has_many :debits, :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => 'debited_account_id'
# ... validators and such ... #
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credited_account, :class => "Account"
  belongs_to :debited_account, :class => "Account"
end
```

This all works, but I am running into some issues with my specs.

Using RSpec and Factory_Girl, I get a TypeError every time I run a spec which calls for the transaction factory.  Rspec output as follows:

```
Failure/Error: transaction = build(:transaction)
 TypeError:
   class or module required
```

below is my spec/factories.rb

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
     #... account factory ...#
  end

  factory :transaction do
    association :credited_account, factory: :account
    #... other attributes set here ...#
    association :debited_account, factory: :account
  end
end
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credited_account, :class => "Account"
  belongs_to :debited_account, :class => "Account"
end
```

to

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credited_account, :class_name => "Account"
  belongs_to :debited_account, :class_name => "Account"
end
```

Comment: Excellent!  That seemed to work!  But now for the real question... why?  And more importantly, why did :class work while running the app, but not for testing?

Comment: @JoshuaFreivald `class` and `class_name` are two different things. The `class_name` is used to define the class name for that association to tell Rails to look for that class name

Comment: interesting.  Definitely something I'm going to do some more reading on.  Thanks again for your help!